# How to close all when I click someone open in Datatables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Add an event listener for opening and closing details. How to close all when I click someone open?

```
$('#laravel_datatable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {

            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row( tr );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }

            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Add below Code After Line var row = table.row( tr );
It will find all class (.shown) from datatable and remove it and hide it

$('.shown').each(function(i, obj) {
    newtr = $(this).closest('tr');
    newrow = table.api().row( newtr );
    newrow.child.hide();
    newtr.removeClass('shown');
});
```